# Info regarding LP Token

Tags: solana-program, liquiditypool, dex

Is there a way to determine whether the LP token has been burned or not?
Also, how can I retrieve the LP token associated with a given token address?
API or any script

I want to provide the LP token address for any token/USDC pair and retrieve the current supply of LP tokens or determine if any LP tokens have been burned or not.

Answer (score 0):

please specifiy which LP token you are talking about.

Any specific defi product? Then you would need to look it up in their documentation probably.

Often the LP tokens are nfts so you could find them by using getTokenAccounts on the wallet and looking through the tokens until you find the ones specific to that platform you are searching for.

There is also the DAS api which lets you easily get information on Tokens.

Comment: I want to provide the LP token address for any token/USDC pair and retrieve the current supply of LP tokens or determine if any LP tokens have been burned.